# Add multiple text to the textarea

Tags: java, textarea

How to add multiple text to the textarea?

I have two methods:

```
public void error() {
       area.setText("error"+"\n");
}
```

and

```
public void processCall(StringBuilder sb) {
    area.setText("Process said:"+sb+"\n");
}
```

When I run these methods, all I get in the text field is

```
Process said:(with the cursor on the next line)
```

The error message gets overwritten. How do I write as much text as I want?

Comment: well, you can always call 'area.getText()' to retrieve what is already there and put it back.

Comment: Swing?  [`JTextArea.append(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29)..

Comment: ..speaking of which.  Swing, AWT, SWT, Android, GWT,..?  It helps to narrow down the GUI toolkit being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace `setText` with `append`

```
public void error() {
    area.append("error"+"\n");
}
```

and

```
public void processCall(StringBuilder sb) {
    area.append("Process said:"+sb+"\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

dont use the `area.setText()` method.

If you want to add the string onto the end of what currently within the textarea then use the `area.append()` method and end all your strings with `"\n"` so that each added string is on a new line

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use the **append** method from the TextArea class

[TextArea Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29)